# css style removes upon page refresh in vue project

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3

When I first go to this link the header footer style is alright-
[image]

But then when I refresh or reload the page, the style is gone. How to fixed this?
[image]

Below is My router.js-

```
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";
import Home from '../components/Home.vue';
import Organization from '../components/aboutus/Organization.vue';


const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    scrollBehavior() {
        return { x: 0, y: 0 }
    },
    routes: [
        {
            name:'Home',
            path:'/',
            component:Home
        },
        {
            name:'Organization',
            path:'/about_us/organization',
            component:Organization
        },
    ],
})
router.beforeEach((to, _, next) => {

    return next()
})
// ? For splash screen
// Remove afterEach hook if you are not using splash screen
router.afterEach(() => {
    // Remove initial loading
    /*const appLoading = document.getElementById('loading-bg')
    if (appLoading) {
        appLoading.style.display = 'none'
    }*/
})
export default router
```

Below is the main.js-

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router/router'
import store from './store/index'

createApp(App).use(
    router,
    store,).mount('#app')
```

Comment: It is because of css is loading at parent component and not in current one, add css at current component as well.

Comment: Then how to solve it? I am new in vuejs, kindly help me understand this

Comment: please share your router config and the main.js

Comment: where do you add your css

Comment: Refreshing the browser reinitializes the Vue application, and if you are not on the initial 'home' page, you can have unexpected results like this.  If you are refreshing the page to try to reload data, I suggest adding a button/link that reloads the data if an API call, or possibly uses the router to route back to itself in order to reload the page/component.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim In App.vue I import them.

Comment: How ? please share `App.vue`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I changed

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

to have exact address for css and javascript files,
and it works!

All css and javascript files are imported in index.html